# How to expose my Python code output using API?

Tags: python, api

I just finished my ML sentimental analysis code and I want to expose the output using an API but I couldn't find anything to help me.

Comment: You need to post your code, preferably a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You could probably try https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi

Comment: Checkout flask, https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/quickstart/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.